# Open custom image via Windows Phone Gallery

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7

I've got some pictures taken by my app. The pictures are displayed in ListBox control. Now, I want to after the click any image, this opened up in the Windows Phone Gallery. I know about PhotoChooserTask, but I don't want that first opened all pictures in gallery, and then, I select the image. Pictures will be viewed directly in the gallery. That is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this issue when I was making [Pin picture](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/pin-picture/01acf962-e179-4829-8cd9-6a1ac7859101) app for Windows Phone 8. So I can say it for sure: there is no way to open photo in system gallery from app. You can do it in Windows Phone 8.1 only.